# Complex .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

can you please let me know htaccess code to redirect there urls:

1. https://www.example.com/forum/news/state-news/archive   to   https://www.example.com/forum/news/state-news?archive=yes
2. https://www.example.com/forum/news/state-news/city-news/archive  to   https://www.example.com/forum/news/state-news/city-news?archive=yes
3. https://www.example.com/forum/news/state-news/city-news/area-news/archive  to   https://www.example.com/forum/news/state-news/city-news/area-news/?archive=yes

My tried htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(core/libraries/|includes|core/includes|core/vb|core/vb5|core/admincp|core/modcp) index.php?routestring=relay/404 [END]
RewriteRule ^css.php$ core/css.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^install/ core/install/ [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please do share your already tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you

Comment: here it is : 
`code`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(core/libraries/|includes|core/includes|core/vb|core/vb5|core/admincp|core/modcp) index.php?routestring=relay/404 [END]

 RewriteRule ^css.php$ core/css.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^install/ core/install/ [NC,L] 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your htaccess Rules file in following way. I have specifically covered 3 URLs shown by you in your question. Please make sure you use these Rules and make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(core/libraries/|includes|core/includes|core/vb|core/vb5|core/admincp|core/modcp) index.php?routestring=relay/404 [END]
RewriteRule ^css\.php$ core/css.php [NC,L]

####I have commented below rule that doesn't make sense, since NO right part in it only condition is mentioned.
####RewriteRule ^install/core/install/ [NC,L]

###New rules added by me to handle 3 different URLs shown by OP in question.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(forum/news/state-news(?:(?:/city-news(?:area-news))))/(archive)/?$ $1?$2=yes [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13 
thanks for your post.

in this rule: 
RewriteRule ^(forum/news/state-news(?:(?:/city-news(?:area-news))))/(archive)/?$ $1?$2=yes [NC,QSA,L]

can we make 'area-news' dynamic. it can be 'area-news', 'colony-news', 'village-news' and son on ?

Comment: @PawanDevelopers, Hey Pawan, buddy could you please be more clear in your question, sorry I didn't understand it.

Comment: @PawanDevelopers, your welcome, happy to help; keep sharing and keep posting Good Q & A on this nice forum, cheers.